I want to change the PayPal payment "Continue to Review" button to "Pay Now." Can I change the button name?
I am using the paypal-rest-sdk package in Node.js. I want to change the payment button name, but I haven't found any solution. If there is any solution, please let me know.
Thank in advance.
import paypal from "paypal-rest-sdk";
paypal.configure({
    mode: process.env.PAYPAL_PROCESS, //sandbox or live
    client_id: process.env.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret: process.env.PAYPAL_SECRET_KEY,
});

const totalPay = findBookingId.totalPrice;

const create_payment_json = {
    intent: "sale",
    payer: {
        payment_method: "paypal",
    },
    redirect_urls: {
        return_url: apiBaseUrl(`paypal/success`) + `?booking_id=${findBookingId._id}&auth=${auth}`,
        cancel_url: apiBaseUrl(`paypal/cancel`) + `?booking_id=${findBookingId._id}`,
    },
    transactions: [
        {
            item_list: {
                items: [
                    {
                        name: "Ride",
                        price: totalPay.toString(),
                        currency: "USD",
                        quantity: 1,
                    },
                ],
            },
            amount: {
                currency: "USD",
                total: totalPay.toString(),
            },
            description: "Stork ride payment",
        },
    ],
};
paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, function (error, payment) {
    if (error) {
        return res.status(400).send({ message: error })
    } else {
        for (let i = 0; i < payment.links.length; i++) {
            if (payment.links[i].rel === "approval_url") {
                // console.log("Link :- ", payment.links[i].href);
                return res.send({ data: payment.links[i].href });
            }
        }
    }
});

I have share the image so look into this.Paypal payment link

that SDK is deprecated, do not use it. And the API is old. See https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/ for integrating the current API with no server SDK
